# CKEditor + CakePHP 3 : Add a plugin

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

I wanted to add CKEditor to my website built with CakePHP3.
I found this [CakePHP Plugin](https://github.com/akkaweb/AKKA-CakePHP-CKEditor-Plugin) which works perfectly well. However I also wanted to add a plugin (Mathjax) to CKEditor.

The CakePHP plugin was not finished so I have modified it a little bit but the add of plugins still doesn't work.

I do not have any printed error but my textarea doesn't display.

I have looked at my source code generated on firefox and it seems that my links to my plugins (mathjax and eqneditor) are wrong. I can't figure out why.

> CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'eqneditor', '/js/ckeditor/plugins/eqneditor/dialogs/', 'eqneditor.js' ); 
>   CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'mathjax', '/js/ckeditor/plugins/mathjax/dialogs/', 'mathjax.js' ); 
>   CKEDITOR.replace( 'body', { 
>   extraPlugins: 'mathjax,eqneditor,' 
>   } );

```
<?php

namespace AkkaCKEditor\View\Helper;

use Cake\View\Helper;
use Cake\View\View;

/**
 * CKEditor helper
 */
class CKEditorHelper extends Helper {

    /**
     * Default configuration.
     *
     * @var array
     *
     */
    protected $_defaultConfig = [
      'version' => '4.5.10',
      'distribution' => 'full',
      'local_plugin' => [
          'mathjax' => [
              'location' =>'/js/ckeditor/plugins/eqneditor/dialogs/',
              'file' =>'mathjax.js'
          ],
          'eqneditor' => [
              'location' => '/js/ckeditor/plugins/mathjax/dialogs/',
              'file' => 'eqneditor.js'
          ]
      ]//local_plugins
    ];

    /**
     * Merged configuration
     *
     * @var type array
     */
    protected $_configs = [];

    /**
     * Local plugins
     *
     * @var type String
     */
    protected $_plugins = '';

    /**
     * Form textarea field CKEditor will be displayed on
     *
     * @var type String
     */
    protected $_field = null;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param View $view
     * @param type $config
     */
    public function __construct(View $view, $config = []) {
        parent::__construct($view, $config);
        $this->_configs = $this->config();
    }

    /**
     * Loads CKeditor into template
     *
     * @local_plugins => [
     *      'abbr' => [
     *          'location' => '/js/ckeditor/plugins/abbr/',
     *          'file' => 'abbr.js'
     *      ],
     * ]
     *
     * @param String $field
     * @param Array $local_plugins
     */
    public function replace($field = 'editor1', $local_plugins =[]){
        $this->_field = $field;

        //If plugins are required ...
        if (!empty($local_plugins)) {
            $this->__setLocalPlugins(); //...add them to CKEditor
            return "
                <script>
                   {$this->_plugins}
                </script>";
      }
      else{ //If no plugin required
            return "
                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.replace( '{$field}' )
                </script>";
      }
    }

    //Load CKEditor
    public function loadJs() {
        $cdn_file = "//cdn.ckeditor.com/{$this->_configs['version']}/{$this->_configs['distribution']}/ckeditor.js";

        return '<script src="'.$cdn_file.'"></script>';
    }


    private function __setLocalPlugins() {
        $plugins = '';

        foreach ($this->_configs['local_plugin'] as $key => $value) {
            $this->_plugins .= "CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( '{$key}', '{$value['location']}', '{$value['file']}' ); \n";
            $plugins .= "{$key},";
        }

        $this->_plugins .= "CKEDITOR.replace( '{$this->_field}', { \n";
        $this->_plugins .= "extraPlugins: '{$plugins}' \n";
        $this->_plugins .= "} ); \n";
    }


}
```

Do you have any idea how to correct this problem ?

Thank you.